# how to assign a value to an array element in c language?

Tags: c

```
#include <malloc.h>

void main()
{
   char **variable;
   int count=0

   variable=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*100);

   for(i=0;i<100;i++)
     variable[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*11);

   scanf("%s",variable[count]);
}
```

Now I want to assign a value to the string present in variable[count]
for example: if `variable[count]` contains a string "abc" then i want to assign 20 to abc
and if i use printf("%d",abc) then it should print 20

Comment: `%d` prints integers, not strings.

Comment: `"if variable[count] contains a string abc then i want to assign 20 to abc "`... so.. you want an array of strings, then you want to assign a integer to a string? Do you mean `abc` is a variable or a string literal `"abc"`? Do you mean a string containing `"20"`?

Comment: yes, abc should be treated as a variable and it is assigned with an integer value 20

Comment: C is a static programming language, which means you cannot create variables in run-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `variable` is `char **`, then `variable` should point to a list of `char *`, not a list of `char`.

Therefore, `variable=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);` should be `variable=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*100);`.

BTW, the type-casting before `malloc()` is unnecessary.

---

> Now I want to assign a value to the string present in variable[count] for example: if variable[count] contains a string "abc" then i want to assign 20 to abc and if i use printf("%d",abc) then it should print 20

You want to treat the value of `variable[count]` to be a variable. Unfortunately, you cannot do that. C is a static programming language, which means you cannot create variable on run time, as you do in dynamic programming language.

But C is powerful enough to let you simulate this. You could create a look-up table, such as

```
typedef struct var {
    char *name;
    int val; /* or whatever type you want */
} var_t;

var_t variable[num_of_vars]; /* or whatever data structure that you can search */
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
variable=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
```

you want to allocate pointers, so specifiy the correct size of a pointer, that is `char*`, like so:

```
variable = malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));
```

or even better like this:

```
variable = malloc(100 * sizeof(*variable));
```

---

Btw: In C there is not need to cast the results of `malloc/calloc/realloc`, nor is it recommended.

---

Following the rules/advices above, this line

```
variable[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
```

should better look like this

```
variable[i] = malloc(11 * sizeof(*variable[i]));
```

---

Finally this call is dangerous:

```
scanf("%s",variable[count]);
```

as it tends to overflow `variable[count]`, so make it save by telling `scanf()` how much so scan in as a maximum, by doing  so:

```
scanf("%10s", variable[count]); /* Leave one (10=11-1) spare for the C-"string"'s 0-terminator. */
```

---

And it's

```
int main(void)
```